# $ f\left(x^{2}+1\right)=f(x) g(x) $ for every $x \in \mathbb{R},$ then

Tags: solution-verification, quadratics

If two real polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ of degrees $m(\geq 2)$ and $n(\geq 1)$ respectively, satisfy
$$
f\left(x^{2}+1\right)=f(x) g(x)
$$
for every $x \in \mathbb{R},$ then

(A) $f$ has exactly one real root $x_{0}$ such that $f^{\prime}\left(x_{0}\right) \neq 0$

(B) $f$ has exactly one real root $x_{0}$ such that $f^{\prime}\left(x_{0}\right)=0$

(C) $f$ has $m$ distinct real roots

(D) $f$ has no real root.

**My approach**

let f(x) has a real root $x_{0}$

$$
f\left(x_{0}^{2}+1\right)=f(x_{0})g(x_{0})
$$
$f\left(x_{0}^{2}+1\right)=0$

it's  indicating $\mathrm{}, \quad\left(x_{0}^{2}+1\right)$ also a root of $\mathrm{f}(\mathrm{x})$

We can assume,
$$
x=x^{2}+1;
x^{2}-x+1=0;
x=\frac{+1 \pm \sqrt{1-4}}{2}=\frac{+1 \pm \sqrt{3}}{2}
$$
So,Not possible, $\left(x_{0}^{2}+1\right)$ also is a root ot $f(x)$ along
With $x_{0}$.

If we go like this ,
let $x_{1}$ is a real root of $f(x)$

$f(x_{1}) = 0$
again
$(x_{0}^{2}+1)$ will also be a root!

So, $f(x)$ will contain infinite root,but that is violating the condition of degree m.
**Hence $f(x)$ has no real roots.**

Comment: So, you build a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of real roots of the polynomial $f$ such that $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+1$. But in irder to prove that $f$ has infinitely many real roots it's not enough to prove that $x_{1}\neq x_0$ (or $x_{n+1}\neq x_n$).

Answer (score 2):

You have shown that $x_0\neq 1+x_0^{2}$ but there is no guarantee that the third root  is different from the first root $x_0$. Instead of this let $x_1=1+x_0^{2}$ and $x_{n+1}=1+x_n^{2}$ for all $n \geq 2$. Verify by induction that $x_n \geq n$ for all $n \geq 1$. This shows that $x_n \to \infty$ so there are infintely many roots.

Comment: so basically my aprroach seems wrong!

Comment: @AmartyaRoy I won't say it is wrong. You just have to work harder to show that you really get infinitely many zeros.